# How can i implement escapeshellarg inside a URL?

Tags: php, linux

The user supplies two variables via a HTML form called username and name.
They are used to execute a shell command which is currently unsafe.
I have the following PHP code:

```
(exec("cat /opt/application/userdata/$username/following | grep -w $name"))
```

I am trying to implement escapeshellarg, but can't get it working by following the official PHP documentation, i have tried:

```
(exec("cat /opt/application/userdata/ .escapeshellarg($username)/following | grep -w .escapeshellarg($name)"))
```

But this is not working and i think its a syntax error.
How do i format this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you are currently trying to run a function inside of a string. This is possible with extra steps, but is not desirable.

What you want to do is concatenate the string with the output of the function.
You can inline that in this manner:

```
exec('cat /opt/application/userdata/' . escapeshellarg($username) . '/following | grep -w ' . escapeshellarg($name))
```

<sup>(noticed I used single quotes [`'`], as no expansion is happening within the string, this is somewhat faster and keeps it separate)</sup>

Or you can perform the operation earlier, and simply include ("expand") the variables in the string, like your first example hints at:

```
$username = escapeshellarg($username);
$name = escapeshellarg($name);
exec("cat /opt/application/userdata/$username/following | grep -w $name")
```

<sup>(noticed I used double quotes [`"`] as there is expansion happening within the string)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `escapeshellarg()` function is a PHP built-in, but you're attempting to execute it as a shell function. You can fix it by simply pulling the function out of the string scope and concatenating the results:

```php
exec("cat /opt/application/userdata/" . escapeshellarg($username) . "/following | grep -w " . escapeshellarg($name));
```